# Kaminari URL not updating using AJAX in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, kaminari

So after ajaxifying the Kaminari pagination links, though the pagination works, the url doesn't update with respective `page number, pgsize` anymore. It works fine without `remote: true` option. Below are the details, am i missing anything ?

**My VIEW:**

```
    <div id="paginator">
      <%= paginate @user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, :remote => true %>
    </div>
```

**MY Controller: Show method**

```
  @user = Kaminari.paginate_array(@properties, total_count: @search_result.total_count).page(params[:page]).per(params[:pgsz] ||= 20)
```

In **show.js.erb**

```
$('#list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'search_result') %>");
$('#paginator').html(" <%= escape_javascript(paginate @user, params: {id: nil, pgsz: 20}, :remote => true) %>");
```

Comment: I think you need to use html5 history api for this. But thanks, I solved one of my problem with your question

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298104/rails-3-update-url-params-with-ajax-request